# How to combine multiple rows into a STRUCT in SQL from a query on Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have an output table that resembles:

| User | Preference |
| --- | --- |
| User A | Pref A |
| User A | Pref B |

I'd like to get the data into the following format:

| User | Preferences, which is array of struct |
| --- | --- |
| User A | [{pref => "Pref A"}, {pref => "Pref B"} ] |

I attempted the following, but to no avail:

```
SELECT
  User,
  ARRAY_AGG(SELECT AS STRUCT(Preference)
  ) as Preferences
FROM
  users
GROUP BY User
```

Curious if anyone might have any pointers? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this snowflake or some other dbms? And you are missing "from" in your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it in Presto, then you can do it like this:

```sql
with raw as (
    SELECT
        t.*
    FROM ( VALUES 
        ('User A',  'Pref A'),
        ('User A',  'Pref B')

    ) as t (user_name, pref)
)

SELECT 
    user_name
    , ARRAY_AGG(CAST(ROW(pref) AS ROW(pref VARCHAR))) as y
FROM raw
GROUP BY 1
```

If you are doing it via Hive, then the option is:

[Check named_struct function is available (should be after Hive 0.8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5qrp.png)

And then simply apply an

```sql
array_agg(named_struct('pref', pref))
```